# Automatically adding menus based on the database

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following problem in .NET Core. I have an application that has a side menu generated from a database, and now my question is how to do it so that you do not have to include this menu in each view, only to be automatically loaded into the side menu. In the symfony framework, I did it like this:

```
{{render (controller (
         'AppBundle: Article: recentArticles'
         {'max': 3}
     ))}}
```

Of course, in addition to the menu, it can be a list of recently added articles which is on every subpage, recently registered, etc.

In the .Net Core I have no idea, some fixed elements such as the search engine I can add in _Layouts.shtml, but how to add such a dynamic menu which is downloaded from the database every time the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using [View component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2). It is a good solution for dynamic menus.

Comment: This is exactly how I solved this by using the ViewComponent

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer would be to make a foreach loop on the page where you want the menu and bind the collection to it creating html tags from the collection. If you want it to be in the _Layout.cshtml file then in addition to the menu data in the collection you would need to add also the view it relates to so you can filter what me u items show on which page. So the example would be something like

```
@foreach (var item in menuItems.Where(x => x.View == "pass the view name"))
{
   <div class="menuItem" name="item.Name"/>
   ....
}
```

Or if you are using some other menu structure as `<li>` or treeList same approach 
different tags :)

The view name can be passed by `ViewData["viewName"]` or `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()`
As it should pass the current view the menu is in and populate the menu respectably

Comment: I would like to get such an effect that this menu would be on every subpage of the website. This is to be a permanent element of the website, but its content is taken from the database. I would like to avoid each time manually adding this menu in every controller and view, I would like to do it on the principle that the page loads automatically when the page is loaded.

Comment: Ok, thank you :) I will try to do that. I'm just learning the .NET Core and unfortunately I'm stuck in this place because I would like to make a dynamic menu, automatically attached to the site.